bean creation is getting failed after upgrading spring boot from 2.7.12 to 3.3.3
before upgrading to spring boot, code was working fine and there was no issue at all.
I have define an interface called EntitySpecRepository and it has five implementation like below.
@Service
public interface EntitySpecRepository {
     ...
}

    @Service
    @ConditionalOnProperty(value = "am.search.els.enabled", havingValue = "true")
    @DependsOn(value = {"elasticIndexUtility"})
    public class ElsEntitySpecRepositoryImpl extends EntitySpecRepositoryImpl {
     ...
       }

@Service("entitySpecRepoRestClient")
      public class EntitySpecRepoRestClient implements EntitySpecRepository {
      ...

     }

 public abstract class EntitySpecRepositoryImpl extends EntitySpecRepositoryHelper implements
        ImpactedEntitySpecRepository {
       .... 
      }

public interface ImpactedEntitySpecRepository extends EntitySpecRepository {
      ....
      }

public class ImpactedEntitySpecRepositoryImpl extends EntitySpecRepositoryImpl {}

in basePackages = "com.xyz.abc" we these all classes are present inside the com.xyz.abc package or nested package.
I am getting below error:
Field entitySpecRepository in com.xyz.abc.spec.service.ProductSpecReloadService required
a bean of type 'com.xyz.abc.sdk.repo.EntitySpecRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

I have autowired
@Autowired
private EntitySpecRepository entitySpecRepository;

in ProductSpecRepository class.
I checked the basePackage directory, it is same and there is no change.
It should work if they are in the same package, bean creation should be successful.
Any help will be appreciated.

Could you please edit your question and add of your code as code.

Show the pom.xml (or build.gradle) that you upgraded. Generally this means you are trying to outsmart the dependency management by managing to much or using incompatible versions.

the @Bean code is missing...how is Spring supposed to know which of the 5 implementations to inject?
